# Using bind to hold a function's arguments in the "this" scope

Tags: javascript, bind

I'm playing around with bind, and the following works:

```
webSQL.InsertTransaction = function(qry,CurrentRow) {
    var local = {};
    // Clone the webSQL.Insert function and add 2 parameters:
    local.InsertTransaction = webSQL.Insert.bind(this,qry,CurrentRow);
    // Call webSQL.Insert(qry,CurrentRow,Transaction)
    dbo.transaction(local.InsertTransaction);
}
webSQL.Insert = function(qry,CurrentRow,Transaction) {}
```

I'd like to simplify it even more.  Can I somehow not have to specify the 2 variables that are in the arguments scope, but instead do something like:

```
local.InsertTransaction = webSQL.Insert.bind(webSQL.InsertTransaction)
```

maybe. My thinking is that then webSQL.Insert can reference qry and CurrentRow from it's "this.arguments" thingy.

Comment: Have you tried `webSQL.Insert.bind(this,arguments)`?

Comment: Well, that works, but then I would have to refer to arg[0].xxx[arg[1]] which isn't very self documenting...

Comment: I want to use the this scope.

Comment: @Phillip: `this` is unrelated to scope. If you wanted `this.qry`, you'd need to assign `qry` to `this` manually, like `this.qry = qry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you were using the object assigned to the `local` variable in the first place.

All you were doing was giving it a function, and then taking that function right back out. Why not skip that step?

```
webSQL.InsertTransaction = function(qry,CurrentRow) {
    dbo.transaction(webSQL.Insert.bind(this,qry,CurrentRow));
}
```

Comment: It's because I'm trying to understand bind is all.

Comment: @Phillip: Pretty simple overall. The `.bind()` returns effectively a copy of the function it was called on... in your case, the `webSQL.Insert` function. The first argument you pass to `.bind()` will permanently set the `this` value of the `Insert` function. The rest of the arguments to `.bind()` will permanently set the first arguments to the `Insert` copy. Any more arguments you pass when you actually invoke the new `Insert` will come after the bound ones.

Comment: How would I construct it so that webSQL.Insert uses this.qry and this.CurrentRow?

Comment: `webSQL.InsertTransaction=function({dbo.transaction(webSQL.Insert.bind(this));}` then do `webSQL.InsertTransaction.apply({qry, CurrentRow})` That should execute `webSQL.InsertTransaction` passing `qry` and `CurrentRow` as part of an object passed through as `this`, you can then use it as `this.qry` or pass `this` on again as local `this` context to other functions and so on.

Comment: Thanks Francois!  After playing with it, I realized that the 'this' scope is too fragile to count on so I'm going to stick with how it's currently written.